# How can I count and fetch records from a model in a single query with Tortoise-ORM?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, orm, tortoise-orm

I have an application in which I use Tortoise-orm to interact with a postgresql database. Then I have the following model:

```
class Dat(models.Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, null=False)
    ext = fields.CharEnumField(enum_type=ExtEnum, null=False)
    granularity = fields.CharEnumField(enum_type=Granularity, null=False)
    status_code = fields.IntField(null=False)
    status_info = fields.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, null=False)
    created_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)

    company = fields.ForeignKeyField(
        "models.Company",
        related_name="dat_company",
        on_delete=CASCADE,
        null=False,
    )

    user = fields.ForeignKeyField(
        "models.User",
        related_name="dat_user",
        on_delete=CASCADE,
        null=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        table = "dat"
```

As you can see, there is a one-to-many relationship between User and Dat.
For a functionality of my application, I need to fetch all the records (applying an optional filter) from Dat together with the "name" field of the User table (which is related to Dat). But in addition, I apply an offset and limit, and I need to count also all the records (but without taking into account the offser and limit).
So, I do it with the following approach:

```
async def get_all_with_count(
        self,
        payload: dict = None,
        skip: int = 0,
        limit: int = 10,
    ):
        query = self.model.filter(**payload)
        model = (
            await query.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    "user", queryset=User.all().only("uid", "name"), to_attr="user_info"
                ),
            )
            .offset(skip)
            .limit(limit)
        )
        total = await query.count()

        return model, total
```

My code works, but I have to do two queries to get what I want. Is there any way to do it with only one query?

Comment: One option is to add a column to the query to hold the total count; e.g., `count(*) AS total_row_count`. This is likely to have a significant adverse affect on performance when querying a large table, but might be better than using two queries. Unfortunately, this approach can be problematic when used with an ORM. This article, [Pagination and the Problem of the Total Result Count](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/) by Laurenz Albe, might be of interest.